# Cant import CSS from MDCTextField to style MDCTextField child elements in LitElement based WebComponent

Tags: lit-element, mdc-components

How do you import CSS into a ES6 module?

I receive the following error in browser console;

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
>   non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is
>   enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Module below:

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from "lit-element";
import { MDCTextField } from "@material/textfield";
import style from "@material/textfield/dist/mdc.textfield.css";

export class MyWC extends LitElement {
  static get styles() { return style; } //was using return css'...'

  render() {
    return html`
      <label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--textarea">
        <textarea class="mdc-text-field__input" aria-labelledby="my-label-id" rows="8" cols="40" maxlength="140"></textarea>
        ...blah blah blah...
      </label>
    `;
  }
```

`@material/textfield` & `lit-element` installed via npm OK. I'm using es-dev-server on linux.

**ps** - I want to use MDC web components but keep things as simple as possible.

Any help appreciated - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML spec currently only allows to `import` javascript modules. This is enforced by checking that the [MIME type](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#fetching-scripts:javascript-mime-type-2) of the imported file is a javascript one, hence the error you're getting. The fact that in some environments (especially with bundlers/transpilers) importing other resource types is possible may give the wrong impression that it is case also in the browser.

To use this kind of import

```js
import style from "@material/textfield/dist/mdc.textfield.css";
```

you would need some tool capable of transforming it into a [`CSSResult`](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/api/classes/_lit_element_.litelement.html#styles). A typical scenario is using bundlers like [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) with dedicated plugins/loaders (ie [rollup-plugin-lit-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-lit-css) or [lit-css-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lit-css-loader)).